# php Multidimensional Array pushing

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to array_push to a multidimensional array?

Creating the array using:

```
$ObjectArray = array();
$ShiftArray = array($ObjectArray);
$WeekShiftArray = array($ShiftArray);
$MasterShiftArray = array($WeekShiftArray);
```

And trying to push to the array using

```
array_push($MasterShiftArray[$last_monday_from_date][$CurrentShift->Offset][$CurrentShift->Shift], $CurrentShift);
```

But I'm getting:

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sandboxj/blog/wp-content/plugins/Shifty/AddShift.php on line 94

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>As the name implies, $ObjectArray is probably an array of objects, not an array of arrays. So you are trying to push values into an object.</strike>

**EDIT**
I'm assuming you're not showing the actual contents of $ObjectArray here BTW. Is this correct?

**EDIT 2**
Hmm, I've tested it now, and the levels you are addressing work fine with the example you're giving, even if the $objectArray holds objects. So there is probably something else going on here which we're not seeing.

Are you sure the $ObjectArray is an array at the time of addressing it?

**EDIT 3**
What do you get when you do a var_dump( $ObjectArray ) right before the array_push call?

Answer (score 0):

you could just do

```
$MasterShiftArray[$last_monday_from_date][$CurrentShift->Offset][$CurrentShift->Shift][] = $CurrentShift;
```